# count how many times a word appears in a specific cloumn bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

this is a file that i have named people.txt

```
10001:Larry Simpson:65:NewYork:555666777
10002:Jonh Fin:91:Rome:333444555
10003:George Jas:86:Amsterdam:777888999
10004:Larry Simpson:65:NewYork:555666777
10005:Jonh Fin:91:Rome:333444555
```

I was trying to count how many people there was on a specific city that is given as argument of the script.

First thing i thought was:

```
grep "$1:" people.txt | wc -l
```

The *":"* was because we can have a city named Amster and another named Amsterdam.

But then I realized that we can have people named Amsterdam, so I tried this to  search in cities column:

```
k=$(awk -F ":" -v loc=$1 -v max=0 ' {if ($4==loc) max++; print max}' people.txt)
echo $k
```

But now the output is like 0 0 1 1 1 and how can I have just the last digit of this output?
I also tried with cut but when doing -f we don´t know how long that output is.

Desired output is just
`1`

Regards

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming $1 is equal to "NewYork":

```
 awk -F: -v loc="$1" '$4==loc { cnt++ } END { print cnt}' people.txt
```

You need to use the END block to print the final count.

Answer (score -1):

You can just do it with a single `grep` command:

```
grep -Ec "^([^:]*:){3}$1:" people.txt
```